# Can't get email field to index correctly in ElasticSearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to setup an email field to index correctly in my mapping.

Because I do not want **email** to be tokenized when it is indexed, I have previously specified the following mapping to allow it to only match search when the entire string matches.

```
{
  "users": {
    "mappings": {
      "user": {
        "properties": {
          "email": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "nickname": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works except that I want the **email** and **nickname** field to be compared as lowercase.

I have tried several ways to specify to change the mapping to use the lowercase token filter.

I have done this with the following:

```
{
  "settings":{
    "index":{
      "analysis":{
        "analyzer":{
          "lowercase_analyzer":{
            "tokenizer":"standard", //Also tried 'Simple' and 'Keyword'
            "filter":"lowercase"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer":"lowercase_analyzer",
          "index": "not_analyzed" //Tried with and without this
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer":"lowercase_analyzer",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "nickname": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "lowercase_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My hope is to allow the following behavior:

- email can be searched and compared as lowercase and should only match if whole email matches
- name is a multi-field used for search and sorting and uses lowercase
- nickname is compared lowercase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try the following and see if that meets your requirements - 
     {

```
  "settings":{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "flat":{
                 "tokenizer":"keyword",
                 "filter":"lowercase"
              }
           }
        }
     }
    },

    "mappings": {
     "user": {
        "properties": {
           "email": {
             "type": "string",
             "analyzer":"flat"
           },
           "name": {
              "type": "string",
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
                }
           },
           "nickname": {
              "type": "string"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```